# can we calculate model accuracy from MAPE or MAE?

Tags: statistics, regression, data-science

In a linear regression model, if MAPE or MAE is caculated, then can we conclude that the regression model accuracy is (1- MAE)*100?

as the MAPE value mostly ranges under 100 and it is commonly used error metric in regression.